# Close RESTEasy client after a certain delay

Tags: redhat, quarkus, resteasy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to close a RESTEasy client after a certain delay (e.g 5 seconds) and it seems the current configuration I'm using is not working at all.

```
     HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionTimeToLive(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5 * 1000)
                    .setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000)
                    .setSocketTimeout(5 * 1000).build())
            .build();

ApacheHttpClient43Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient43Engine(httpClient, localContext);

ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().httpEngine(engine).build();
```

according to the documentation the ConnectionTimeToLive should close the connection no matter if there's payload or not.

please find attached the link

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html-single/developing_web_services_applications/index#jax_rs_client

In my specific case, there sometimes is some latency and the payload is sent in chunks (below the socketTimeout interval hence the connection is kept alive and it could happen that the client is active for hours)

My main goal is to kill the client and release the connection but I feel there is something I'm missing in the configuration.

I'm using **wiremock** to replicate this specific scenario by sending the payload in chucks.

```
.withChunkedDribbleDelay
```

any clue about the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using .withFixedDelay(60000) instead of .withChunkedDribbleDelay().

Comment: in thi case .withFixedDelay(60000) doesn't reproduce the scenario I'm trying to solve, since after the fixed delay it will send me the payload in one shot.
What I want to reproduce is a payload being sent in chunks with a certain delay between each chunk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).